# Teamcity - save build parameters in produced artifact

Tags: teamcity

I build j2ee aplication as WAR with teamcity.
I want keep the same WAR name and save build parameters in produced artifact.

What the best way to save  teamcity build parameters (like build.number, svn.revision, buiild.date etc) inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
echo build.number=%build.number% > prop.properties
```

is what I do in a TeamCity build step to directly record parameters to a file.